# Non-example of mathematical assertion.

Tags: logic

In my logic class they gave this as a non-example of a statement.

"Suppose n is divisible by 3."

I can vaguely see why it is not a statement, but don't really see how I would defend that sentiment, if asked.  Also, if not a statement (or assertion) what kind of thing is this?  Is it a supposition?  I've seen that word used and it *seems* to apply here...

Is it not an assertion because n is not well-defined?

Comment: It is a supposition, yes. A statement or assertion could be: "$n$ is divisible by $3$." Here you are not actually *asserting* the divisibility; you are merely supposing it.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman, "$n$ is divisible by $3$" is not a statement until you quantify $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If we take **statements** to be the sort of things that can be **true** or **false**, then it's easy to see that:

> "Suppose $n$ is divisible by $3$"

is *not* a statement, since it has no truth-value. We could maybe call it a 'command'. Its component:

> "$n$ is divisible by $3$"

is also *not* a statement, because, as Santiago Canez pointed out in a comment above, unless $n$ is quantified over, unless the formula is 'closed', the expression will continue lacking a truth-value.

---

It's been pointed out to me that it's not very obvious why the main sentence is not a statement, so let me bring a concrete non-mathematical example. Consider the sentence:

> "Suppose you are Australian"

Is this sentence true or false? (what do you think?) I think no. It is certainly either true or false whether you or any other particular person is Australian. But the sentence supposing one or the other itself has no truth-value. I chose this particular sentence with 'you' in it, because 'you' is an indexical and like '$n$' in the original sentence needs a context to obtain an actual value, so:

> "you are Australian" ($\sim$ "$n$ is divisible by $3$")

is also lacking a truth-value until the 'you' is replaced by the name of an actual person. I hope the analogy is helpful. If it's not, leave a comment and I'll try to come up with a better one.

Comment: It isn't that obvious to me that "Suppose n is divisible by 3" cannot be evaluated as either true or false.  Just a matter of which n you select...

Comment: Can it ever be false? What's the truth-value of "suppose n = 3 and n != 3"?

Comment: @hefalump I've added an analogy to my post; see if that helps.

Comment: Hm, that is helpful to see what you are getting at.  I guess I have trouble thinking of any sentence a human could put down on paper as not, in some sense, either true or false.  "Suppose P" seems more like an agreement that P is true.  But then, "P is true" is a statement, while "Suppose P is true" is technically different... so let's just say I understand - because I have a better grip on my misunderstandings - and I could certainly spot officially non-statements from the crowd.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @hefalump "Suppose P" is a meta-statement, that is, a statement but not the object language, but in the language we use to speak about the object language. That's another way of looking at things. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase from your logic class is not a statement because it does not meet the correct grammatical criteria. The sentence "Suppose $n$ is divisible by $3$" is an *imperative* sentence, meaning that it commands the reader; but a statement should be a declarative sentence (see the Wikipedia articles on [sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_sentence#By_purpose) and [statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28logic%29) for more information). An imperative sentence does not express a fact: it is more a request -- "Can you suppose, for the sake of my argument, that $n$ is divisible by 3?" -- than an assertion -- "You are supposing that $n$ is divisible by $3$". This sort of construction is common in mathematics: other examples include "Let $n$ be divisible by $3$"; "Assume $n$ is divisible by $3$"; "Divide $n$ by $3$ to conclude that . . ."

Don't feel bad about being confused about what constitutes a statement: philosophers can't even agree on that point. Bertrand Russell believed that "Pegasus exists" *is* a statement but P.F. Strawson thought it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is well-defined. It is a variable. However, it's not a statement due to the word "**Suppose**" in the sentence. Thus, it is a supposition. Rather, a statement would be when you "state something", e.g., "$n$ is divisible by $3$". The previous sentence in quotes is equivalent to writing: "We state that $n$ is divisible by $3$", which is obviously a statement.

Comment: "We state that we suppose n is divisible by 3."  They kind of seem like the same things to me - assertions and suppositions, with the distinction that we agree not to try to disprove suppositions.

Comment: @hefalump "We state that we **suppose** n is divisible by 3" - as I remarked above, it's not a statement due to the word "suppose" in the sentence.